# Content View resize to the parent scroll view

Tags: swift3, uiscrollview

My scroll view have content view with a lot of components and the components are animating while clicked. There is one problem, the content view does not change the size properly. Does any one have any idea how to fix this ? While scrolling size of the contnent view following on it. Here is a code describing that what I am doing :

```
 func updateDropDownList(tableView: UITableView, height: CGFloat, state: CGFloat) {
        let rowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            var frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.width, height: height)
            tableView.frame = frame
            if state == -1 {
                frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)) * rowHeight)
            }
            self.updatePositions(tableView: tableView, frame: frame, state: state, rowHeight: rowHeight)
        })
    }
```

state :

1. state = 1 // resize table view
2. state = -1 // back to the oryginal size

And method which allows me to change positions of each component :

```
func updatePositions(tableView: UITableView, frame: CGRect, state: CGFloat, rowHeight: CGFloat) {
        switch tableView {
        case facilitiesTableView:
            statusLabel.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            statusTableView.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            serviceTableView.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            vehiclesCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            colorsCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            scrollView.contentSize.height += state * colorsCollection.frame.height
//            contentView.frame.size = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
        case statusTableView:
            serviceTableView.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            vehiclesCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            colorsCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            scrollView.contentSize.height += state * colorsCollection.frame.height
        case serviceTableView:
            vehiclesCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            colorsCollection.frame.origin.y += state * (frame.height - rowHeight)
            scrollView.contentSize.height += state * colorsCollection.frame.height
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

There is one commented line which resize the content view but while i invoke this it going to mess me screen, the clicked table does not gonna resize becouse content view which have these components going to redraw them if i am not wrong.

Without resized conent view to fit a scroll view I can not click on the lowest components,c uz they are out of bounds of the content view.

Thanks in advancd!

Answer (score 0):

In my observation these issues occur as constraints are not updated along with animations that occur.
Try adding the following line of code just before and after animation is done

```
contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This little line of code has helped me on multiple occasions. Hope it works for you!

Comment: If i add it before the animation it is not gonna help and if i put it after it is not gonna let me to click even of the table view - it wont stretch

Comment: are you using any layout constraints?

Comment: I am. Like top, bottom, leading and trailing to scroll view, each one is 0, and equal hight and width with a superview of scroll view.